# Add some custom text to logs shown by protractor-beautiful-reporter

Tags: javascript, logging, protractor, automated-tests

I'm using `protractor-beautiful-reporter` and would like to know if there's a way of adding my own logs into the html report is generates.

For now, I don't find it really practical since it shows messages like `TimeoutError: Wait timed out after 5009ms` while my custom logs would show something like `ERROR: the login popup did not show`.

Thanks in advance for your insights!

Comment: hey. I think your problem is not the reporter, but the spec that throws incomplete error. Reporter just displays whatever protractor logs. So you need to deal with that. The error example you brought looks like the error is coming from `browser.wait`. Let me know if this is the case, I can show a workaround that helped me to solve the same problem

Comment: Hi @SergeyPleshakov, the problem is that I want every possible log that I throw during the test (for example `Enter login` `Enter password` `Press button` `Login successful` etc.) I don't get any of these logs with `protractor-beautiful-reporter`.

Comment: I'll just give you the direction to look in. Essentially you have several tasks to solve to implement what you want. First, write logs to a file. Maybe it'll be even enough to have html report and a separate file with logs. If you still want to attach it, you can overwrite your plugin so it connects the logs. or just add a block in afterLaunch that will just write the content of the log file to the html report. I went with the second option, but I use `protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter`

Comment: Oh thanks Sergey I'll try this!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly, so, you have to add reporting capabilities to your Jasmine scripts with additional node modules if you are looking for customized reports.

Depending on what kind of reporting you are looking for, you can use any of the npm modules readily available and create your own custom framework with Protractor and Jasmine.

Some of the commonly used npm modules for reporting:

- [protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com%2Fpackage%2F@www.npmjs.com/package/@virtocommerce/protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter)
- [jasmine-spec-reporterzx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spec-reporter)
- [protractor-beautiful-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-beautiful-reporter)
- [protractor-html-reporter-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-html-reporter-2)

Most of these reporters can be used to generate HTML, XML reports of the test run, take screenshots on spec failures or format the basic run status in your console.

Further, you can use the generated XML files to integrate with your CI tools as well.

Basically, you have the freedom to choose and create your own custom framework according to your needs.

Comment: Hello Ilya, thank you for your answer but it's kind of generic and it doesn't answer my question which is specifically about `protracto-beautiful-reporter`. Good day and welcome to StackOverflow :)